# Is It possible to execute a Nearest Neighbor (Fuzzy) Query in TSQL / SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running queries against a baseball database and was wondering if its possible to write a query that returns the nearest neighbors (Top 20 to 50) baseball players with statistic and demographics nearest to what is included in the Where clause query.  For example,

```
Select Top 20 Player_ID, Player_FullName 
From BaseballDB
Where Age = 23 And BattingAvg = 250 And OPS = 100
```

I've used equal signs in my query although for what I'm trying to achieve the value doesn't actually have to be equal I'm just looking for players that fall close to an intersection of the dimensions included in my Where Clause.

I am familiar with Nearest Neighbor analyses in predictive analytics, but I am just curious if its possible to achieve something similar with SQL.

Comment: something like `sqrt((col - X value) ^2 + (col2 - YValue)^2 + (col3 - Zvalue)^2)` and then get `MIN`/order by this distance?

Comment: You could use a range selection (`age >= x and age <= y` ect') ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you need to define what the distance metric is.  Nearest neighbor is not one particular method; it depends on the definition of the metric.

For instance, one metric is Manhattan Distance. This would be implemented as:

```
select top (25) b.*
from baseballDB b 
order by abs(age - 23) + abs(battingavg - 250) + abs(ops - 100);
```

If you square the values instead of using `abs()`, you have the familiar Euclidean metric (the square root is not needed for ordering purposes).

For various reasons, Manhattan Distance is probably not a suitable metric for this data (the different columns have different ranges).  But this shows how to implement the nearest neighbor in a database.

I should point out that databases are not generally optimized for this type of query, so it requires sorting all the data.  There are ways to optimize nearest-neighbor, but those optimization are generally not available in databases for bespoke metrics.

Comment: - Thanks for the response.  I was thinking it might be helpful to normalize all of my data so they fall between 0 and 1. Then the Manhattan Distance may make more sense.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor . . . I generally recommend standardization (subtract the average and divide by the standard deviation) or doing the work in the space of principal components.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do something like
Raise it to a power so a big difference in any one makes a big difference
Divide to normalize

```
declare @Age int = 23, @Bat int = 250, @OPS int = 10, @pw float = 2;

select Top 20 Player_ID, Player_FullName 
from BaseballDB
order by (@Age + power(abs(@Age - age), @pw)) / @Age 
       + (@Bat + power(abs(@Bat - bat), @pw)) / @Bat
       + (@OPS + power(abs(@OPS - OPS), @pw)) / @OPS  desc
```